# How to take a function as user input on MAPLE?

Tags: maple

If I want to take a function as a user input how do I do that?

I tried to input $x^2$.

`s0:=readstat("Enter function:");`

`s:=x->s0;`

```
s(2);
```

But this only returns $x^2$

Answer (score 1):

Use **unapply**, as in **s:= unapply(s0, x);**
You cannot use a local or formal variable in **readstat** input.

Answer (score 0):

@CarlLove's answer is a better idea, but yet just as another way, you can use `eval` and a new variable name.

```
s0 := readstat( "Enter function:" ); # enter x^2
s := x0 -> eval( s0, x = x0 ); # it substitutes every x in s0 by x0
s(2);
```

Here is what you will get.

[image]